# Convert probability vector into target vector in python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am doing logistic regression on iris dataset from sklearn, I know the math and try to implement it. At the final step, I get a prediction vector, this prediction vector represents the probability of that data point being to class 1 or class 2 (binary classification).

Now I want to turn this prediction vector into target vector. Say if probability is greater than 50%, that corresponding data point will belong to class 1, otherwise class 2. Use 0 to represent class 1, 1 for class 2.

I know there is a for loop version of it, just looping through the whole vector. But when the size get large, for loop is very expensive, so I want to do it more efficiently, like numpy's matrix operation, it is faster than doing matrix operation in for loop.

Any suggestion on the faster method?

Comment: vec=prob>0.5...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix('0.1 0.82')
print(a)

a[a > 0.5] = 1
a[a <= 0.5] = 0
print(a)
```

## Output:

```
[[ 0.1   0.82]]
[[ 0.  1.]]
```

## Update:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix('0.1 0.82')
print(a)

a = np.where(a > 0.5, 1, 0)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 5):

A more general solution to a 2D array which has many vectors with many classes:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array( [ [.5, .3, .2], 
                [.1, .2, .7], 
                [ 1,  0,  0] ] )

idx = np.argmax(a, axis=-1)
a = np.zeros( a.shape )
a[ np.arange(a.shape[0]), idx] = 1

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: it really helps

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1:** If you do binary classification and have 1d prediction vector then your solution is [numpy.round](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html):

```
prob = model.predict(X_test)
Y = np.round(prob)
```

**Option 2:** If you have an n-dimensional one-hot prediction matrix, but want to have labels then you can use [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html). This will return 1d vector with labels:

```
prob = model.predict(X_test)
y = np.argmax(prob, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to procede with a confusion matrix etc. afterwards and get the original format of a target variable in scikit again: `array([1 0 ... 1])`you can use:

```
a = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
a = np.where(a>0.5, 1, 0)
```

The `[:,1]` referes to the second class (in my case: 1), the first class in my case was 0

Answer (score 0):

for multi class, or a more generalized solution, use

```py
np.argmax(y_hat, axis=1)
```